# Matplotlib - getting no spaces between multiple lines with matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, heatmap

How to have no spaces between subplots in this example ?

(And keep a good visualization if I have more lines)

I've seen that what we see can change a lot with a value for figsize.

So do we have to guess the "correct" value for figsize ?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.matshow([[1,2,3,4,5]])
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax.matshow([[5,4,3,2,1]])
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

I've tried to use something different like gridspec but I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: The reason you're getting no spaces between your subplots even when specifying `wspace=0, hspace=0` is due to using `matshow`/`imshow` without `aspect='auto'`.  Matplotlib's layout model can be a bit confusing at first. Not to plug my own answer too much, but there's a more complete explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633322/changing-aspect-ratio-of-subplots-in-matplotlib/32635933#32635933  In short, you'll either have to use `aspect="auto"` with `matshow` or change the size of your figure.  You can also use the `axes_grid1` module to do this, as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Tight Layout Guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html), you would use it like `plt.tight_layout()` with parameters to control the padding for your figures to make them fit nicely.