# Jupyter/Geopandas plot order breaks figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, figsize

I've got a notebook ([github link](https://github.com/RubeRad/camcom/blob/master/geopandas_figsize.ipynb)) where I'm using geopandas to draw maps with various countries colored. Depending on the order of the plots, sometimes it doesn't respect the figsize() I specify. I'm seeing this behavior repeatably in jupyter running locally in Ubuntu 20.04 and Firefox, and both Binder and Colab running in Chromium.

Can somebody help me understand what's going on? Is this a bug or am I controlling geopandas/matplotlib wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
sixc = world[ world['continent'] != 'Antarctica' ]
asia = world[ world['continent'] == 'Asia' ]
noam = world[ world['continent'] == 'North America']
swed = world[ world['iso_a3'] == 'SWE' ] 

# This works, makes a 2x1 landscapey aspect
axes = sixc.plot(figsize=(8,4), color='lightgrey')
asia.plot(ax=axes, color='green')
noam.plot(ax=axes, color='purple')

# Plotting swed at the end breaks figsize, makes it squareish
axes = sixc.plot(figsize=(8,4), color='lightgrey')
asia.plot(ax=axes, color='green')
noam.plot(ax=axes, color='purple')
swed.plot(ax=axes, color='yellow')

# Plotting swed in the middle makes it ok again
axes = sixc.plot(figsize=(8,4), color='lightgrey')
asia.plot(ax=axes, color='green')
swed.plot(ax=axes, color='yellow')  
noam.plot(ax=axes, color='purple')
```

(Also, for some (but not all!) of my students, that broken plot also has no lightgray background countries. Is that likely a result/side-effect of whatever is causing the aspect problem?)

Comment: What's the version of geopandas? Run `gpd.__version__`

Comment: gpd.__version__ == 0.8.1

Comment: That is, that's the version of gpd on my laptop, which is presumably what is in use when I use local jupyter (I don't do 'environments'). colab also gets 0.8.1 from "!pip install"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `geopandas` v 0.8.1 you are using, the `default` aspect ratio of the plot commands you use is `auto`. Thus, the output plots you obtained will have unpredictable value of aspect ratio. Try

```
print(axes.get_aspect())
```

for each plot. In previous version of geopandas, one will get `equal` as output, and the plots are correct. But in your case, you will get values that do not represent equal aspect.

For a simple fix of your problem, you can add this line of code:

```
 axes.set_aspect('equal')
```

after the last plot statement.

Comment: Thx for the concise version!

Comment: Good one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633322/changing-aspect-ratio-of-subplots-in-matplotlib) regarding how aspect ratio works in `matplotlib`; however, although the concepts are helpful, `GeoSeries.plot` is built on top of matplotlib, so that answer might not help in terms of the code that would solve the problem.

The easiest thing to do is to pass `aspect='equal'` to each `GeoSeries.plot` as [default is `'auto'` for "aspect" in link)](https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.plot).

As for your other issue, I cannot reproduce, and I would have those students upgrade to the latest versions or use a different IDE. This works for me in a Jupyter Notebook.

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
sixc = world[ world['continent'] != 'Antarctica' ]
asia = world[ world['continent'] == 'Asia' ]
noam = world[ world['continent'] == 'North America']
swed = world[ world['iso_a3'] == 'SWE' ] 

# This works, makes a 2x1 landscapey aspect
axes = sixc.plot(figsize=(8,4), color='lightgrey', aspect='equal')
asia.plot(ax=axes, color='green', aspect='equal')
noam.plot(ax=axes, color='purple', aspect='equal')

# Plotting swed at the end breaks figsize, makes it squareish
axes = sixc.plot(figsize=(8,4), color='lightgrey', aspect='equal')
asia.plot(ax=axes, color='green', aspect='equal')
noam.plot(ax=axes, color='purple', aspect='equal')
swed.plot(ax=axes, color='yellow', aspect='equal')

# Plotting swed in the middle makes it ok again
axes = sixc.plot(figsize=(8,4), color='lightgrey', aspect='equal')
asia.plot(ax=axes, color='green', aspect='equal')
swed.plot(ax=axes, color='yellow', aspect='equal')
noam.plot(ax=axes, color='purple', aspect='equal')
```

[image]

Also, as a sidenote that dataset has some irregularities with `99` as the `ISO` code. I believe it is getting fixed in an update (see https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1041).... you can use the below code to fix them manually:

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.loc[world['name'] == 'France', 'iso_a3'] = 'FRA'
world.loc[world['name'] == 'Norway', 'iso_a3'] = 'NOR'
world.loc[world['name'] == 'Somaliland', 'iso_a3'] = 'SOM'
world.loc[world['name'] == 'Kosovo', 'iso_a3'] = 'RKS'
```

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer and the link! So then does aspect='equal' mean "Equal to what was already in the Figure/Axes from previous plots"? I would have assumed it would mean "Equal height/width, i.e. square" 

(EDIT) I see now, it means equal scale for x/y units, which in this case spreads longitude out twice as wide as latitude

Comment: Also thx for testing for the other issue (no lightgray countries). I am baffled by this, as we were all running the same github-hosted notebook in Colab, and not one but two students got different results!